# Series expansion of $(x;x)_\infty$ at $x=1^-$?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

The so called [Euler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFunction.html) is implemented in *Mathematica* as

```
QPochhammer[x, x]
```

I have been trying to obtain its leading behavior for $x\to 1$ from below. Unfortunately, *Mathematica* does not produce a result if I try

```
Series[QPochhammer[1-ep,1-ep],{ep,0,0}]
```

since it just returns

> `QPochhammer[1-ep,1-ep]`

Numerically, I noticed that the function falls off slower than `1/Gamma[1/x]`. Is there any way to find the leading behavior using *Mathematica*, which I have missed? Thanks for any suggestion!

**EDIT:**

Additionally to the excellent answer posted below, one can find the asymptotic behavior of the function of interest in eq. (8) of the [q-Pochhammer MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) page. Thanks to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) for directing me to this page.

Comment: The equivalent `Series[q^(-1/24) EllipticTheta[2, π/6, q^(1/6)]/Sqrt[3], {q, 1, 4}]` yields a rather horrendous-looking expression.

Comment: @J.M. The main term seems OK to me: `Refine[Normal[
  Series[q^(-1/24) EllipticTheta[2, π/6, q^(1/6)]/Sqrt[3], {q, 1, 
    0}]], 9/10 < q < 1]`

Comment: @J.M. This is very interesting. I wonder where did you find the equivalent expression as an `EllipticTheta` function? To my knowledge there is no page for q-deformed Pochhammer symbols on wolfram functions webpage. Is there another such database which is more complete?

Comment: The relevant expressions are in the MathWorld page for $q$-Pochhammer, but you certainly can prove the relation yourself (but that is a question for math.SE).

Comment: I see, so you just recognized it to be this function by directly looking at its structure, not looking it up in a database. OK, thank you!

Comment: Actually, I meant that the identities relating $q$-Pochhammer and $\vartheta$ and $\eta$ are all in MathWorld, but I had tried to prove them myself as an exercise, many moons ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Result*

Let

```
f[x_] = QPochhammer[x, x];
```

It can be easily shown that for `x` close to 1 `f[x]` has the leading behaviour

$$\text{fa}(\text{x})=\exp \left(-\frac{\pi ^2}{6 (1-x)}\right)$$

Comparision of function and leading term

```
Plot[{1, Log[f[x]]/Log[fa[x]]}, {x, 0.9, 1}]
```

[image]

Very close to `x = 1` the numerical precision becomes poor but still the result is convincing.

*Derivation*

First of all the Mathematica documentation for QPochhammer[x,x] gives the definition as an infinite product

```
fp[x_] := Product[1 - x^n, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

Checking it

```
fp[x]

(* Out[233]= QPochhammer[x, x] *)
```

Now consider the `Log` of `fp`

$$\text{lgf}=\log (\text{fp}(x))=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \log \left(1-x^n\right)$$

Expanding the `Log` gives

$$\text{lpf}\text{:=}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{k n}}{k}\right)$$

Changing the order of summation
$$\text{lpf}\text{:=}-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } x^{k n}}{k}$$

The n-sum is a geometric series which can be summed up to gives

```
s = -(x^k/(-1 + x^k));
```

Now we expand `s` about the point x = 1

```
Series[s, {x, 1, 1}] // Normal

(* Out[241]= -(1/2) - 1/(2 k) - 1/(k (-1 + x)) + (1/(12 k) - k/12) (-1 + x) *)
```

Taking only the leading term in `1/(1-x)` and inserting it into the k-sum gives

$$\text{lpf0}\text{:=}-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -\frac{1}{k (k (x-1))}$$

The k-sum can be done explicitly

```
Sum[1/k^2, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[242]= \[Pi]^2/6 *)
```

hence the result follows. QED.